# python: outfile to another text file if exceed certain file size

Tags: python, file-io

I using scapy with python in ubuntu. I would like to ask if anyone would know how to code the example:

let say I have two text files which are writing while the script is running then I would like to check the file is exceed example 500bytes, if does then it will store whatever in the file and create a new text file to write. (output1.txt, output2.txt,etc..)

Would be appreciated if any expertise will help. Thanks

---

part of my code is:

```
file = open("output.txt","w")

def example(p):
    if p.haslayer(Dot11Beacon):
        if p.addr2 not in uniqueAP:
            file.writelines(p.addr2 + "\n")
```

---

so while the script is running in the terminal, it will write it into the file called output.txt but i would want to improve the script to check file size of the text file and if exceed it would stop writing in the current and create a new output2.txt for example and continue.

Comment: I would keep track of the bytes written to each file within your program, within a special file writer class, for example. Anyway, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you mean _the script_ is writing to the files, or something else and you just check the size?

Comment: I would look into [RotatingFileHandlers](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A simple example if you don't want to use [RotatingFileHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler).

You should use `os.stat('filename').st_size` to check file sizes.

```
import os
import sys

class RotatingFile(object):
    def __init__(self, directory='', filename='foo', max_files=sys.maxint,
        max_file_size=50000):
        self.ii = 1
        self.directory, self.filename      = directory, filename
        self.max_file_size, self.max_files = max_file_size, max_files
        self.finished, self.fh             = False, None
        self.open()

    def rotate(self):
        """Rotate the file, if necessary"""
        if (os.stat(self.filename_template).st_size>self.max_file_size):
            self.close()
            self.ii += 1
            if (self.ii<=self.max_files):
                self.open()
            else:
                self.close()
                self.finished = True

    def open(self):
        self.fh = open(self.filename_template, 'w')

    def write(self, text=""):
        self.fh.write(text)
        self.fh.flush()
        self.rotate()

    def close(self):
        self.fh.close()

    @property
    def filename_template(self):
        return self.directory + self.filename + "_%0.2d" % self.ii

if __name__=='__main__':
    myfile = RotatingFile(max_files=9)
    while not myfile.finished:
        myfile.write('this is a test')
```

After running this...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ ls -la | grep foo_
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_01
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_02
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_03
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_04
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_05
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_06
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_07
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_08
-rw-r--r--  1 mpenning mpenning    50008 Jun  5 06:51 foo_09
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks Mike Pennington you saved my life! But is it possible to add current date to the filename when it has done written with the file? example: foo_*current-date*_01, etc.

Comment: @leong, if my answer was useful, please consider accepting it.  You can add the date to the filename by changing the return value of `filename_template()` to be `return self.directory + self.filename + str(datetime.date.today()) + "_%0.2d" % self.ii`.  If you do this, also `import datetime` at the top of the script

Comment: nice! sorry one last question: will it works with date plus current time?

Comment: actually my the other concept is filename by current date-plus-time with millisecond, then if all are same it will then increase the `ii`, if not it will use the current date-plus-time for the name. i tried replace with `str(time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S:%f"))` but error.

Comment: leong, you should use `str(datetime.datetime.now()).replace(' ', '_')`; however, the [os keeps file creation time as metadata (at least to second precision, sometimes to millisecond precision)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/237082/667301), so I'm surprised that you'd want to write the file creation time into the filename

Comment: although I said creation time, remember that you can also get last modification time if you like

Comment: recently I tried to change the output dir but it doesn't seem to work. Now the problem is if i change `directory='/home/user/Output'` it did not output the text file to the dir of the folder of "Output" instead it name the text file to the same dir and the text filename goes "Output<Whatever_My_Filename>".

Comment: Please use `directory='/home/user/Output/'`

Comment: Nice answer, I'm curious if there's any reason *not* to do a similar thing but using `self.fh.tell()` instead of `os.stat(path).st_size`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way (a bit shorter) would be to use a `with` clause having an `if` condition checking for the file size:-

```
def RotateFile(count, file_size, file_name):
    indX = 0
    while indX < count:  
        with open(file_name,"a") as fd:  
            ##
            fd.write("DUMMY TEXT\n")      
            ##  
            if int(os.path.getsize(file_name)) > file_size:
                indX += 1
                file_name = "new_file"+str(indX)+".txt"
```

`with` statement creates a context manager, so by the time you reach the end of `if` condition , the file object in `fd` will have been automatically closed.

Next is to specify the options you need and pass on to the method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    count = 10                           ## 10 number of files
    file_size = 10000                    ## 10KB in size
    file_name = "new_file.txt"           ## with this name
    RotateFile(count, file_size, file_name)
```

After execution, it will give 10 files of size 10KB each (in the current dir)...

[image]