# bash if [[ =~ regex compare not working?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a value in a variable that may be absolute or relative url, and I need to check which one it is.

I have found that there's a `=~` operator in `[[`, but I can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
url="http://test"
if [[ "$url" =~ "^http://" ]];
    then echo "absolute.";
fi;
```

Comment: [Recommended reading on Regular Expressions in Bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1)

Comment: Regarding your latest deleted question.  As you deleted it, I was typing an answer based on one of my [previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894692/python-outfile-to-another-text-file-if-exceed-certain-file-size); perhaps it will help

Comment: @MikePennington I just wanted to avoid any more downvotes, after I found out that `global` is not needed there at all, it was all clear.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use regex without quote:

```
url="http://test"
if [[ "$url" =~ ^http:// ]]; then
    echo "absolute."
fi
```

This outputs `absolute. as regex needs to be without quote in newer BASH (after BASH v3.1)

**Or avoid regex and use glob matching:**

```
if [[ "$url" == "http://"* ]]; then
    echo "absolute."
fi
```